# Fast KL Transform

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and I want to implement the fast KL transform.

I already found a way to implement the KL transform but I need to implement the fast KL and as I understood all I have to do is change the initial matrix.

this is my matrix now:

```
im=imread('lena.bmp');
im=rgb2gray(im);
x = double(im)/255; %convert to double and normalize
[n m]=size(x);

y11=reshape(x(1:n/2,1:m/2),(n^2/4),1);
y12=reshape(x(1:n/2,m/2+1:m),(n^2/4),1);
y21=reshape(x(n/2+1:n,1:m/2),(n^2/4),1);
y22=reshape(x(n/2+1:n,m/2+1:m),(n^2/4),1);
x=[y11,y12,y21,y22];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this scientific article can help you:

http://parnec.nuaa.edu.cn/zhangdq/nerocomputing05a.pdf

but unfortunately it doesn't have an implemented code as you asked for.

Good look!

Comment: Thanks the article looks very good, but some code would be very helpful, or a small suggestion on what I need to change. Thank you.